# Send local notification based on system time on Iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

In my app, a user will set date and time for reminder, and the phone needs to send local notification at that particular time even when the app is closed.

Able to send a notification at particular time using the below method. but it doesn't work when app is closed:

```
public func simpleAddNotification(hour: Int, minute: Int, identifier: String, title: String, body: String) {
    // Initialize User Notification Center Object
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    // The content of the Notification
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = .default
    content.badge = 1


    // The selected time to notify the user
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute

    // The time/repeat trigger
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    // Initializing the Notification Request object to add to the Notification Center
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Adding the notification to the center
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if (error) != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but did you ask for permission to send notifications? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

Comment: Hi, Yes, permission obtained. Still unable to get notification